# How to run a git repo on terminal as a command?

Tags: git, terminal, repository

I have cloned a git repository and want to run it as a command on terminal.

I couldn't find a satisfying solution myself. Also I'm doing all this stuff on Linux.
The repository is https://github.com/mweitzel/firetower.

Comment: Repositories store source code, not programs. Please elaborate, and if the repo you're referring to is public, linking it will allow people to provide more detailed help.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Which repository did you clone and what do you mean when you say you want to run it as a command ?

Answer (score 2):

Once cloned, it is likely that said cloned repo folder is not part of your $PATH.

By default on Linux, the current doler is *not* in your $PATh either, so if you just type `firetower`, it won't work ("command not found").

You need:

```
cd /path/to/your/local/cloned/repo/firetower
./firetower "node server.js"
# or 
./firetower "rspec"
```

Note the `./` in front of the `firetower` executable shell script command.

The alternative is to follow the [installation section](https://github.com/mweitzel/firetower#installation), and add the script in a folder which is part of your `$PATH`.